# JSON-LD in Mediawiki pages

Tags: mediawiki, json-ld, microdata

I have a wiki that uses microdata for structured data and I want to switch to json-ld. How do you go about that? microdata is pretty straight forward but when I try adding json-ld code to pages (<script...) it doesn't parse and just becomes text on the page. Is there an extension to allow json-ld into wiki pages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From a quick web search, I could not find any such extension, but it should be rather simple to create your own

Comment: That's way out of my class XD I was thinking the page needs a link to the json-ld vocabulary or something as mediawiki doesn't understand the script.

Comment: No really, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extensions - it's not much harder than installing an extension

Comment: Gonna give it a try. Thanks.